# Display checkboxes checked based on user choice

Tags: vue.js

My app receives an array of occupations as an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "value": "string",
    "selected": false
  },
  ...
]
```

The `occupations` array is initialized to `[]` in `data`:

```
data: function() {
        return {
            api: this.$store.state.api.user,
            ...
            occupations: [],
            selectedOccupations: []
        }
    }
```

The `occupations` array receives the actual api data in `created()`:

```
this.api.someApi((error, data, response) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log('fail fetching occupations:', error);
            } else {
                this.occupations = data;
            }
        });
```

Some of the occupations get checked by the user and saved to the database.

How do I display the occupations checked by the user as checked in the list of all occupations?

Comment: Could do a key-value pair for each received occupation (which kinda already happens if you just do ```this.occupations = data``` via its indexes). Then, wherever you show the checkboxes in html, give them you ```v-for="(occupation, index) in occupations"``` and ```v-model="occupations[index].selected" for the checkbox input within the ```v-for``` loop. Then, on submit, you submit ```this.occupations``` and run through its objects ```selected``` value or submit only the values themselves via key of occupation id.

Comment: Where is your markup?